# bluie pris Error msg : Internal : Cannot store output in Success because it is on another page, and has been hidden

Tags: blueprism

whenever i run macro in blue prism this msg come 
Internal : Cannot store output in Success because it is on another page, and has been hidden
 any solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to run a stage that has an output linked to a data item called "Success".

This error indicates there is no data item named "Success" that is either (a) on the current page, or (b) has its "Hide from other pages in the process" box unchecked.